# The Python 3 Turtle module > .goto() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

May I get an explanation about the turtle module command:

```
.goto(0, 0)
```

I know that this command moves the turtle but I'm trying to find out what these arguments inside the parentheses exactly mean, in details?

Thanks.. your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the first parameter is the x-coordinate and the second parameter is the y-coordinate. So, calling this function will move the turtle to whatever (x, y) point that you give it.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html?highlight=goto#turtle.goto